# How to make a program work 10 seconds? and after 10 seconds the program will stop

Tags: java

```
public class RandomPrint {
    public static void randomprint(){
        for (int i=0;i<100000000;i++){
            System.out.println((int)(1+Math.random()*10));
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        long begain = System.currentTimeMillis();

        long CheckTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(true){
            RandomPrint.randomprint();  //this is the program need to work
            CheckTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
            if((CheckTime-begain)>=(10*1000)){
                System.out.println("10 seconds stop!");
                break;
            }
        }
   }    
}
```

This is my java code, the program is "randomprint()" ,but after 10 seconds,the program does not stop!(the program will be always working). Can you help me to make the program stop working after working for 10 seconds ?  thank you!

Comment: When you debug, what happens?  Are the values what you expect them to be?  Where specifically does the behavior of the code differ from what you expect?

Comment: This is why debuggers exist.

Comment: Your program seems to work as per expected desire (runs for 10 seconds and then stops). What's not right?

Comment: where do you call randomprint()? are you calling it from a different thread? is the huge for loop on the same thread as the timer? If randomprint doesnt return then you arent able to check the time

Comment: There is  "RandomPrint.randomprint();"  between the "while(true){" and "CheckTime = System.currentTimeMillis();".   But  after 10 seconds,the program does not stop!

Answer (score 0):

In method randomprint remove the for-loop completely but keep it's one-line body and it will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Well i made some changes to your code, as the for will loop we have to break it , so we will break it in the time you wanted, now this time i will pass the time to your method, look

```
public static void randomprint(int seconds){
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long end = start + (seconds)*1000; //  seconds * 1000 ms/sec
      for (int i = 0;i<100000000;){
        System.out.println((int)(1+Math.random()*10));
        i++;
        if(System.currentTimeMillis() >= end) break;


    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Stop my program at 3 seconds
        randomprint(3);

}
```

Change the number 3 for a 10 and there you got ;)

Comment: OK，no problem,but ldont know how to give you the point, can you show me the step?  thank you!

Comment: l am really very sorry for you ,l click too much times on the arrow and the "0" become "1",but soon become "0" again.

Comment: ty so much , np =)